# TabView lifecycle issue if views are the same

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have `TabView` containing 2 entries....both trigger display of `StationListView`.  The issue I have is that when I click on 2nd tab, the `onAppear` is being called twice (once each for the 2 instances) having the effect of data for 2nd tab showing, following shortly by data again for 1st tab.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var cityBikesViewModel = CityBikesViewModel(repository: CityBikesRepository())
    @State private var selection = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            StationListView(cityBikesViewModel: cityBikesViewModel, network: "galway")
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "location")
                        Text("Galway")
                    }
                }.tag(0)
            StationListView(cityBikesViewModel: cityBikesViewModel, network: "oslo-bysykkel")
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "location")
                        Text("Oslo")
                    }
                }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct StationListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var cityBikesViewModel : CityBikesViewModel
    var network: String
 
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(cityBikesViewModel.stationList, id: \.id) { station in
                StationView(station: station)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Bike Share"))
            .onAppear(perform: {
                self.cityBikesViewModel.fetch(network: self.network)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Full code at https://github.com/joreilly/BikeShare/blob/master/ios/BikeShare/BikeShare/ContentView.swift

Comment: You should manage this (redundant requests drop) by view model (or even below engine) instead of view, which behavior is not controlled by you.

Comment: @Asperi I think I know what you're getting at but still not clear on what would be the trigger point for fetching the data when user clicks on each tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd like the view to reload the data from the network when it is selected.  Unfortunately, `.onAppear` doesn't work because the View isn't loaded when you select it.

Instead, reload the data when `selection` changes.

To make this work in SwiftUI 2.0 (Xcode 12), pass the `tag` number and `selection` (as a `Binding`) to the `StationListView`, then have `StationListView` reload the data when the `tag` matches the `selection` both `.onAppear` and when `selection` changes using `onChange(of: selection)`:

```
struct StationListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var cityBikesViewModel : CityBikesViewModel
    var network: String
    var tag: Int
    @Binding var selection: Int
 
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(cityBikesViewModel.stationList, id: \.id) { station in
                StationView(station: station)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Bike Share"))
            .onChange(of: selection) { _ in
                refreshData()
            }
            .onAppear {
                refreshData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func refreshData() {
        if tag == selection {
            cityBikesViewModel.fetch(network: self.network)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `TabView`:

```
TabView(selection: $selection) {
    StationListView(cityBikesViewModel: cityBikesViewModel, network: "galway", tag: 0, selection: $selection)
        .tabItem {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "location")
                Text("Galway")
            }
        }.tag(0)
    StationListView(cityBikesViewModel: cityBikesViewModel, network: "oslo-bysykkel", tag: 1, selection: $selection)
        .tabItem {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "location")
                Text("Oslo")
            }
        }.tag(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: update pushed to https://github.com/joreilly/BikeShare